# Connect to Windows Media Player in Delphi

Tags: delphi, media-player

I would like to write an application that starts/stops, and fades in/out the running instance of `Windows Media Player`. I only have `Delphi` knowledge and failed to convert all those `c++` and `c#` samples that are about this Topic.
 Can someone help me to get this  `IServiceProvider` and `IWMPRemoteMediaServices` implemented?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My read of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564264(v=vs.85).aspx) is that those interfaces are not meant to control a running instance of media player from your program, but to work with a embedded player and let the player show in full mode while staying attached to your application.

Comment: Maybe you'll be more comfortable with [automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I believe it would provide most of the functionality as the interfaces provide. Ex: `wmp:=CreateOleObject('WMPlayer.OCX');` `wmp.OpenPlayer('C:\Test.mp3');` etc..

Comment: Will the Automation method not create a new instance of WMP? I Need to control the running, full version of WMP. And thats what I read of the documentation. :-)

Comment: @Wolfgang - Why don't you try? It's only two lines.. Anyway, it seems so (doesn't launch a new instance)..

Comment: Alright, alright! :-)
What Type is WMP in your example? WHen I make it an Idispatch the Compiler wont accept the "Openplayer" and it wont let me make a TWIndwsMediaPlayer...
Sorry if asking stupid questions, but this whole stuff is new to me. I just Need the object to work with, then I'll be fine.

Comment: @Wolfgang - It's an OleVariant. See any Delphi ole automation example on the web and you'll figure it out quickly. BTW, insert a '@' when you're replying to a comment so that the person is notified. :)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - Thanks I just figured it out. I was using Outlook like this once and fetched that code back into Memory! :-)
Now I'm one step further. I can use the OPENPLAYER method, but it seems I can't Access the CONTROLS-Object.
`wmp:=CreateOleObject('WMPlayer.OCX');
WMP.OPenPlayer('Somesong.mp3');
WMP.Controls.Stop;`

But it doesnt stop!

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - WORKING! If i open the file using the URL-property then I can start and stop it. VERY STRANGE... :-)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - No, this is not what I intended. I find no way of Controlling a runnning WMP. My application is handling its own invisble WMP if use the URL property (so that i can stop and start the Music). If I use the OpenPlayer method, I get a new WMP-Windows, but I cant control it...

Any Ideas?

Comment: @Wolfgang - Sorry, no. I've never used it.

Comment: @WolfgangBures: If you have other questions regarding automation of Media Player, *start a new question on that topic*. This question is "Can someone help me to get this IServiceProvider and IWMPRemoteMediaServices implemented?", and that question has been answered.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily work with those interfaces in Delphi.

Create a new wrapper for the type library:

- File->New->VCL Forms Application
- Component->Install Component->Import Type Library
- Choose Windows Media Player, v1.0 (the one that points to the WMP.DLL)
- Click `Finish`

To clarify which type library to import:

[image: Import type library dialog]

Add the generated `WMPLib_TLB.pas` unit to the uses clause of your application. You'll find it in your `$(DELPHI)\Imports` folder.

The imported type library includes both of the Windows Media Player interfaces you mention.

Follow any of the examples you found elsewhere, using the interfaces in the imported type library. (You can post efforts to use them that you can't figure out here as new specific questions that include the code you're not able to get working.)

Comment: @Sertac: Thanks. I didn't see it when I looked, but also didn't see anything saying you couldn't (which is why I said "don't believe" instead of "can't"). :-) Edited to remove that statement, though, and to clarify that both mentioned interfaces are in that type library.

Comment: I did exactly that, but I cant find the two Interfaces. :-(

Comment: Then you imported the wrong one of the two type libraries (which is why I mentioned "the one that points to WMP.DLL"). You can see it by hovering over the file location column in the import dialog (where you select the type library). Both of the interfaces you list **are** in the type library if you import the correct one - I verified that specifically before posting my answer.

Comment: strange, I only have ONE "Windows Media Player" ad it is the wmp.dll. I'm trying the Automation Approach...